# Why Daenerys isn't considered a witch by these people?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *Game of Thrones* S06E04

> Daenerys burns all the Dothraki Khals and then comes out of the burning house. Then all the Dothraki that came to see what was happening knelt before her, considering her the new leader of the horde because she 'defeated' the other Khals.

**Why would she be considered a Khaleesi and not a witch? Why did the Dothraki decide to follow her?** It's seems like witches are a bad thing in Westeros, Essos and especially in the Dothraki culture. In the eye of a Dothraki man, I feel like she should be seen as a witch for surviving/creating the fire.
Also, there are probably a lot of Dothraki/Khalasars that probably don't want to be ruled by some foreign girl.

**EDIT :** I think the Dothraki in the show does not believe she is a witch because I think Dothraki would not follow a witch. Witches seem to be a very bad thing in the eyes of this culture (see how the Dothraki girls in S06E03 were saying that Daenerys was a witch and that they should kill her, and after the event of the season 1 also).

So, if you think that the Dothraki might think that she's a witch but decide to follow her nonetheless, **why would they agree to follow a witch even though witches are known to be a bad thing in this culture?**

Comment: Who says they don't? If tomorrow someone used some weird magic to burn every world leader alive and then demanded your allegiance, would you kick up a fuss?

Comment: Good point, however, I still feel like the proud dothrakis would have at least try to fight her. Dothrakis are proud and they're less afraid of death than most people.

Comment: The Dothraki seem to have a clear preference for a **strong** leader. If you think they would not accept a "witch" as their leader, I suggest you edit your question to explain why you think so.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll add that. It seemed obvious for me so I didn't think to add it.

Comment: Because her cats are huge and breathe fire.

Comment: Well, at this point the dothrakis most likely only heard rumours of the dragons. After they see the dragon (Drogon, in the next episode) I understand more the choice of the dothrakis to follow her.

Comment: They don't think she's a witch because they think she is a God!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The Dothraki have no other option.** Daenerys has just created a power vacuum where she is the only one to fill the void.

When Khal Drogo died and the dragons were hatched by the fire Daenerys used to burn the witch Mirri Maz Duur, Drogo's khalassar still had other options. They had a choice to stay with Daenerys or join a new khalassar that was formed by Drogo's Bloodrider.

Now, all the other Khals are gone. Daenrys emerges as the one who defeated them. The Dothraki will only follow a winner, a disgraced Khal is no Khal at all.

I think the horde in general will see her more as a god than a witch. She is not performing blood magic or any types of spells. She is immune to fire and can control dragons!

Comment: Jorrah Mormont told her as she sailed from Quarth that she would have a Khalassar when she proved herself strong. She has done that.